# get sharepoint file programatically (I know the url from a web browser)

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft365

I use sharepoint from a web browser.

I visualize a file (xls file) that has following url

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7Bxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx%7D&file=filename.xlsx&action=default&mobileredirect=true

If I right click on the document and and I click on 'Copy URL' I get a url of the type:

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/XXXXXXXXX-sXXXXXXXX?e=yyyyy

My question is how can I programatically get this document:

I tried using Office365-REST-Python-Client (version 2.5.2)

and manage to get a client context (authentication with **same** username and password as used on my browser)

with following snippet:

```
import os

from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

def get_ctx():
    sharepoint_url = os.environ["SP_URL"]
    username = os.environ["SP_USER"]
    password = os.environ["SP_PASSWORD"]
    auth_ctx = AuthenticationContext(url=sharepoint_url)
    auth_ctx.acquire_token_for_user(username, password)
    ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url, auth_ctx)
    return ctx
```

I manage to list all existing document_libraries and each items in them

```
def get_doc_libraries(ctx):
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()

    lists = web.lists
    ctx.load(lists)
    ctx.execute_query()
    for sp_list in lists:
        props = sp_list.properties
        if props['BaseTemplate'] == 101:  # Document libraries
        library_name = props["Title"]
        doc_library = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(library_name)
        ctx.load(doc_library)
        ctx.execute_query()

        items = doc_library.get_items()
        ctx.load(items)
        ctx.execute_query()

        paged_items = doc_library.items.paged(500, page_loaded=print_progress).get().execute_query()
        for item in paged_items:
          # do_something_with_item
```

I get a few thousand items which might be realistic for this sharepoint url, but most of the items don't have titles and I don't know how to find out whether any of these is refering to the document that I have a url for.

Attempts of using

```
def get_file_with_rel_url(ctx, url, sharepoint_url):
    sharepoint_url = sharepoint_url.rstrip("/")
    rel_url = url.replace(sharepoint_url, "")

    response = File.open_binary(ctx, rel_url)

    with open("bla.xls", 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(response.content)
```

do fail.

I get an error messageof the kind

`{"error":{"code":"-2130575338, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"fr-FR","value":"Le fichier /:x:/g/XXXXXX-XXXXXX n'existe pas."}}}`

Which means in English
`The file /:x:/g/XXXXXX-XXXXXX doesn't exist`

I think the urls given by the web browser aren't the ones I should use in the API.

But I don't know how to determine the right url or how to get something like a uid for the document, that I can use to fetch it.

The file I look at is not a file, that I own.
It has been shared by somebody else, but I have read and write permissions to it (in my browser)

Comment: Better to use Power Automate to get your files. Because you are very hard to overcome these sign-in credentials, as well as your org policy-configuration as well. With PA, you can easily handle and send out the file as REST. This link may helpful for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/

Comment: How would this theoretically work?

After setting up some power automate magic I could specify a document and whenever the document changed it would be copied to a certain destination?

Comment: Yes it can, PA Sharepoint has Trigger will listen to the change of a document and Action to send to specific location you want, email to you or do whatever you want

Comment: OK have to see if documentation is understandble for me and whether PA sharepoint is something we have or something we had to pay for.

Comment: It is within M365 along with your org subscription including Sharepoint online, outlook,… mostly Triggers and Actions developed by MSFT are free.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: I gave up . . .

I can't get the data with my credentials.

The workaround that Tab Nguyen suggests fails, as the web interface of PA freezes all the time. So I can not even try out whether it would be working.

I'm using now an embarassingly stupid workaround which I don't like.
I run a periodic task, that is running on a windows machine, that has the given sharepoint file synced to its local disk.

I was naively hoping that I can either use app credentials or just my username and password and find a way to get a file non interactively without a browser